# auth0-js multi factor authentication without Lock

Tags: javascript, authentication, cross-domain, auth0

I am trying to use auth0-js for MFA. I don't want to use Lock as I prefer a custom login/signup flow.

From what i understand, there is no way to call `/challenge/mfa` with auth0-js, so I am doing it with axios. The problem is that this raises a cross orign error:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I can't find how to allow cross origin requests in Auth0 Client interface for MFA challenges